# Alternate or getSupportFragmentManager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an app for Android 2.2+ and I need to use Fragments. So I added the support library into my project and have been successfully working with Fragments until now.

When I type:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager()
```

nothing happens. I get an error. So is there an alternate way for going about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to a) make sure you activity extends `FragmentActivity` and not just activity and b) make sure your fragment extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and **not** `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Sorry I had to wait until my time limit was up.